# Getting 404 error while access nested modules after deploying into server

Tags: angular, tomcat, deployment, module, angular-cli

I am building an angular 4 application with ng build --prod --base-href="/myapp/". This is working for components which are there in the main modules . But getting  404 for the components inside nested modules. if i work with hashstrategy it is working for nested modules. But My requirement is not to have hash on the url.
can you help me how can get it ...

Tried with PathLocationStrategy also...still not working

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: tomcat apache server

Comment: If you take a look at the request that gives you a 404, you can see that the url is something like `/myapp/supmodule`. The problem is, that tomcat will not know that `/myapp/supmodule` isn't a path. There exists a config for tomcat, but I don't know how it is called.